# OpenCV in Qt crashes on deallocation of vector of lines when using HoughLinesP

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I've been using OpenCV 3.0.0 for quite some time now and have recently switched IDEs from Visual Studio 2013 to Qt Creator 3.4.2. I rebuilt my OpenCV libraries from source `WITH_QT` checked. I'm now having a problem at runtime with deallocating a `vector<vec4i>` when using the HoughLinesP function ONLY in debug mode.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
Mat source(400,400,CV_8U,Scalar(0));
line(source,Point(20,20),Point(300,300),Scalar(255),10);
{
    vector<Vec4i> lines;
    HoughLinesP(source, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 50, 50, 10 );
    cout << "lines.size() = " << lines.size() << endl;
    cout << "before leaving block" << endl;
}
cout << "after leaving block" << endl;
imshow("source", source);
waitKey();
return 0;
```

If I run this in release, then everything works fine and this is my output:

> lines.size() = 13
>   before leaving block
>   after leaving block

However, if I run this in debug, then my program crashes when it reaches the closing block and this is my output:

> lines.size() = 18446744073709306522
>   before leaving block

If in debug and I comment out the line with HoughLinesP, then there is no crash and this is my output:

> lines.size() = 0
>   before leaving block
>   after leaving block

Here is my .pro file:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = OpenCVProject_x64
TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += C:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\include

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
    LIBS += -LC:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\OpenCVLocalBuild_x64\lib\Release \
        -lopencv_calib3d300 -lopencv_core300 -lopencv_features2d300 \
        -lopencv_flann300 -lopencv_hal300 -lopencv_highgui300 \
        -lopencv_imgcodecs300 -lopencv_imgproc300 -lopencv_ml300 \
        -lopencv_objdetect300 -lopencv_photo300 -lopencv_shape300 \
        -lopencv_stitching300 -lopencv_superres300 -lopencv_ts300 \
        -lopencv_video300 -lopencv_videoio300 -lopencv_videostab300
}
win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    LIBS += -LC:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\OpenCVLocalBuild_x64\lib\Debug \
        -lopencv_calib3d300d -lopencv_core300d -lopencv_features2d300d \
        -lopencv_flann300d -lopencv_hal300d -lopencv_highgui300d \
        -lopencv_imgcodecs300d -lopencv_imgproc300d -lopencv_ml300d \
        -lopencv_objdetect300d -lopencv_photo300d -lopencv_shape300d \
        -lopencv_stitching300d -lopencv_superres300d -lopencv_ts300d \
        -lopencv_video300d -lopencv_videoio300d -lopencv_videostab300d
}

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Please let me know if you have ideas on whats causing this crash.

Comment: What compiler did you use for building OpenCV? What compiler is used for Qt project?

Comment: Not sure what compiler I was using. Where would I find that in Visual Studio and Qt Creator?

Comment: You should know your compilers. Qt Creator is just an IDE. You can have many build profiles for projects with different compilers and Qt versions. To exclude possiblity of incorrect project build we need to understand your setup. When you built `opencv` you had to provide to `cmake` your compiler. It could find by default VS or you can set MinGW. I see in project name with `x64`, so I assume that it is 64 bit compilation. However, you could download 32 bit Qt with MinGW, VS2010, 2012, 2013, or 64 bit Qt for VS 2013.

Comment: When using cmake I selected `Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64` with `Use default native compilers` checked. And this is the qmake build step `qmake.exe OpenCVProject_x64.pro -r -spec win32-msvc2013 "CONFIG+=debug"`. So I guess the compiler used in Qt is `win32-msvc2013`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**qmake Language: Scope Syntax**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-language.html#scope-syntax):

> Scopes consist of a condition **followed by an opening brace on the same
>   line**, a sequence of commands and definitions, and a closing brace on a
>   new line:
>
> ```
> <condition> {
>     <command or definition>
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> **The opening brace must be written on the same line as the condition.** Scopes may be concatenated to include more than one
>   condition, as described in the following sections.

Both library sets are added to the `LIBS` variable for `Debug` and `Release` build, since scope opening braces are written on the new line after conditions.

It appears that at least for `Visual Studio 12 Win64` and `OpenCV 3.0` there is binary incompatibility between `Debug` and `Release` libraries.

If the application is built in the `Debug` mode with the `Release` libraries it crashes and if it is built in the `Release` mode with the `Debug` libraries it also crashes.

Comment: I moved the scope braces to be inline with the condition statement and that didn't solve my problem. As a second test, I even commented out both the release and debug condition lines, as well as, all of the lines adding the release libs and I still had the same problem.

Comment: @Stanton Are you sure that the project is rebuilt with new .pro (run qmake, rebuild)? For sure the braces were incorrectly opened. I can reproduce the problem only with wrong library sets. If you use VS12 x64 for OpenCV I would expect you to use Qt for Windows 64-bit (VS 2013). However it would be strange that it is able to compile release if something is completely wrong. You can check in debug build directory current `Makefile.Debug`. The `LIBS` variable should contain only debug libraries.

Comment: Problem solved. It was a combination of the placement of the scope braces, running qmake, and rebuilding. Originally when I moved the scope braces I only ran qmake, then ran the program. However, I had to do both run qmake AND rebuild, as you suggested. Thank you very much for your assistance!!