# Why is cv::split is crashing using QT?

Tags: qt, opencv

I am a new user for QT5 and openCV. Actually i am tring to capture Images by a camera, afterwords i try to split the captured Images into 3 channels (RGB) using cv::split. Unfortunately i got the following error

**"The program has unexpectedly finished.
C:\bla_bla_bla.exe crashed"**

Here is the code i use:

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(CV_CAP_ANY);

while(capture)
{
    Mat frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);

    std::vector<Mat> rgb; // OR std::vector<Mat> rgb(3) ;


    if(frame.empty())
    {
        continue;
    }

    //Separate the frame to 3 (R,G,B) channels
    else
    {
        cv::split(frame, rgb);
    }
}
```

**Note: the same code is working fine with visualstudio 2012/2013.**

Comment: 1) can you run it in debug and provide error description? 2) You should use `VideoCapture`, not legacy `CvCapture` 3) planes will be BGR, not RGB,

Comment: Do you have a problem only with that function or openCV is not usable at all? There are linkage issues in Windows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33175811/opencv-in-qt-crashes-on-deallocation-of-vector-of-lines-when-using-houghlinesp

Comment: @Miki: 
1) the debug mood is not working well , so i am not using the debug mood.
2)VideoCapture gives the same result: crashing
3) good to know that

Comment: @Orest Hera: i think the Problem is in split function, i have another CV function where are wotking fine.

Comment: 1) well, too bad. it's difficult to debug not in debug mode :D. Also, why it doesn't work well? 2) Ok, but better use VideoCapture. Can you provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? This code is working for me. 3) :D

Comment: for you, Is it working with QT creator?